# real analysis uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider some function $g_{n}:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ \ni \ \{g_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to some function $g$. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $\ G_{n}:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ by $\ G_{n}(x)=\int_a^x g_{n}(t)dt$ and define $G:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $G(x)=\int_a^x g(t)dt$. Prove that $\{G_{n}\}$ converges uniformly to $G$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$|G_n(x)-G(x)|\le\int_a^x|g_n(t)-g(t)|dt\le(b-a)||g_n-g||_\infty$$

Comment: Very nice hint, indeed! +1

Comment: What do the double bars in the end mean?